# Highlight clicked button with React/Tailwind

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I want to change the appearence of an button after clicking it.
I have tried adding focus: / active:, but react is re-rendering the component on-click, so it doesn't work.

In Javascript I would add an event-handler to every button that would automatically change the appearence after being clicked, how am I able to recreate that in react/tailwind-css, since tailwind is not working with dynamic className changes?

Is there a good practice, or should I add if statements in order to make it work?

This is what I am trying to recreate.

```
HTML:
<button>MY BUTTON</button>
<button>MY BUTTON</button>
<button>MY BUTTON</button>
```

```
JS:
let button_list = document.querySelectorAll("button");
button_list.forEach(element=>{
  element.addEventListener("click",function(){
    button_list.forEach(remove_background=>{
      remove_background.style.background="white";
    });
    this.style.background="black";
  });
});
```

Comment: Any code snippets that represents an example on how it works? You can put a working example inside CodeSandbox

Comment: Can't you just use tailwind's ```active:``` pseudo-class like this: ```bg-blue-400 active:bg-blue-600``` or what do you mean by 'active'? I think 'active' refers to an unfinished click of the button, so it shouldn't be re-rendered during the 'active' state, because ```onClick``` only triggers once you let go of the mouse-click

Comment: I added an working example: https://omn6tu.csb.app/

Comment: @maxeth Thanks for explaining what the active state means, that's not what I am looking for then. I want to change the background-color AFTER the button has been clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend a state variable to store the active button. Here's a simple example:

```
const ButtonList = () => {
  const [activeButtonIndex, setActiveButtonIndex] = useState(0);
  return (
    <>
      <button
        className={activeButtonIndex === 0 ? "bg-white" : "bg-black"}
        onClick={() => setActiveButtonIndex(0)}
      >
        My Button
      </button>
      <button
        className={activeButtonIndex === 1 ? "bg-white" : "bg-black"}
        onClick={() => setActiveButtonIndex(1)}
      >
        My Button
      </button>
      <button
        className={activeButtonIndex === 2 ? "bg-white" : "bg-black"}
        onClick={() => setActiveButtonIndex(2)}
      >
        My Button
      </button>
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that is what I was looking for, I had the state, but wasn't sure how to dynamically add the styling. The only issue is that it looks really messy, since the button has a lot of styling, which has to be included in both statements.

Comment: My general approach for shared tailwind styles is a combination of the classnames nom package (https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames) and storing shared classes in a string variable. Something like this:
`const sharedClasses = "bg-white p-4...";`
`<button className={classnames(sharedClasses, "m-4 rounded ...")}/>`